# Leave former application after starting a new activity of another application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

I have an activity in my Android application that can be started by other applications by using some intent filter. When my activity is started by another app it is titled with the application name that started it (and not with the one it belongs to) in the [recents screen](https://developer.android.com/design/handhelds/index.html). This is also true when my activity never returns to the other app, but just starts other activities of my app.

How do I "finish" the calling app and make sure that everything is associated with my app?